# Guake Terminal throws pynotify attribute error

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal

I regularly use Guake terminal on Ubuntu. Recently, it stopped working. When I try to run it using terminal following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py", line 43, in <module>
from guake.guake_app import Guake
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py", line 49, in <module>
import guake.notifier
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/notifier.py", line 31, in <module>
pynotify.init("Guake")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

The source code of the concerend file can be found [here on GitHub repo.](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/guake/blob/master/src/guake.py) I have pynotify installed on the system. There seems to be a problem with pynotify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a names conflict with `pynotify`.

I had installed `pynotify` from PIP using:

```
sudo pip install pynotify
```

Since that was the wrong choice, I removed it with:

```
sudo pip uninstall pynotify
```

And then installed the expected `pynotify` using:

```
sudo apt install python-notify
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a conflict with pynotify but couldn't figure out where. I have 2 quick followup questions: 1. Why pip installation is wrong choice? 2. Why did guake gets uninstalled while uninstalling python-notify?

Comment: @mraduldubey: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to either of those questions.